# Change location of image depending on cell value

Tags: excel, charts, location

I need to change the location of an image depending upon the value in cell A1. If it is 1, the image needs to below column c, if 2 then below  column d and so on up to 5. Possible ?

Any help would be much apreciated

Answer (score 0):

Just write this vba code for the Change event of the worksheet containing the picture.
Here I assume the picture name is "Picture 1" change it at will

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim v
If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
 v = Target.Value
 If IsNumeric(v) Then
  If v >= 1 And v <= 5 Then
   With Shapes("Picture 1")
    .Top = Cells(1, 2 + v).Top
    .Left = Cells(1, 2 + v).Left
   End With
  End If
 End If
End If
End Sub
```